# How to trace errors in debug.log for WooCommerce 3.0?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, debug

I found a debug log error that states:

> price was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: `require('wp-blog-header.php')`, `require_once('wp-load.php')`, `require_once('wp-config.php')`, `require_once('wp-settings.php')`, `do_action('wp_loaded')`, `WP_Hook->do_action`, `WP_Hook->apply_filters`, `WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action`, `WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_handler_variable`, `WC_Cart->add_to_cart`, `do_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart')`, `WP_Hook->do_action`, `WP_Hook->apply_filters`, `WC_Cart->calculate_totals`, `do_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals')`, `WP_Hook->do_action`, `WP_Hook->apply_filters`, `after_before_calc_totals`, `WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong`. This message was added in version 3.0.

I cannot find where to start with this.

All the templates in the theme are updated to the latest.
I am currently looking in the `functions.php` to find out if it the error is there. But still having no luck.

Comment: I always direct users [to follow steps like these](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info).

Comment: search for the function `after_before_calc_totals` in your plugins or theme.

Comment: Somewhere you have `->price` (which you can also search for), where it should be `->get_price()`

Comment: Found them in the functions.php.  Will be updating on how I fixed it maybe tomorrow.